# Smooth doodling over canvas

Tags: android, performance, canvas, svg

I have a custom view, refer the following answer
[Eraser effect using canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414609/eraser-effect-using-canvas)
The problem is whenever I doodle over the screen I am unable to write smoothly, But I have seen applications like 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viettran.INKredible&hl=en
and 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apalon.notepad.free&hl=en
which has really smooth writing irrespective of the phone I am using. How are they achieving something like that? I know they use SVG for lossless zooming but experience of writing is very different.

Comment: I have tried cubicTo function also for smoother paths but no visible improvement was noticed.

Comment: This answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/33882382/3877726 it show how to smooth lines created via the mouse. It is adaptable and based on tried and tested algorithm.

Comment: I tried that but doesn't seems to help much.